# How to convert a JSON file to a Tensorflow tensor or tensordataset

Tags: python, json, tensorflow

I realize that this might be a simple question, but I have been searching for a straightforward answer and cannot find it, neither in the documentation or on forums.
The threads I have found were about very specific questions like converting audio to a tensor via JSON.

So my question is: How do I convert a JSON file to a Tensorflow tensor or tensordataset to then use it to train a neural network with Tensorflow?

Update:

I planned on doing this by creating a pandas dataframe from the JSON file and then creating a Tensor from the dataframe. The problem I am running into now is that my JSON has multiple nested levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgive my shallow knowledge,the way I thought is convert json to numpy,then convert numpy to tensor

```
import json
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

json_input = '{"rings" : [[[-8081441.0, 5685214.0], [-8081446.0, 5685216.0], [-8081442.0, 5685219.0], [-8081440.0, 5685211.0], [-8081441.0, 5685214.0]]]}'
rings = np.array(dict["rings"])
rings = tf.convert_to_tensor(rings, tf.float32, name='rings')
```

I am not sure if there have direct way for json to tensor, hope it can help you :)

Comment: I found that there is CSV to Tensor documentation on the Tensorflow website. There they go through numpy or pandas en then to a Tensor. Since JSON can also be put in numpy and pandas, I am planning to use one of those.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the structure of your JSON data.

You can try this:

```
import json
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

features = np.array(data['features'])
labels = np.array(data['labels'])

features_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(features)
labels_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(labels)
```

Comment: Now I run into the problem that my JSON has multiple levels.